# Core data: Failed to process pending changes before save. The context is still dirty after 100 attempts

Tags: ios, core-data

I've been trying to find the cause of this crash from crashlytics:

> Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException Failed to process
>   pending changes before save. The context is still dirty after 100
>   attempts. Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad
>   validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.

I do use -willSave in two places in my code, I suspect the culprit is this, but I'm not sure why:

```
- (void)willSave {
    if (self.isDeleted) {
        PPInventory *inventory = [self primitiveInventory];
        [self unMonitorInventory:inventory];
    } else {
        PPInventory *inventory = [self primitiveInventory];
        NSMutableSet *missingItemIdSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[inventory itemIds]];
        NSMutableArray *expiredInvItems = [NSMutableArray array];
        if (inventory != nil) {
            for (PPInventoryItem *invItem in [self inventoryItems]) {
                NSString *itemId = invItem.itemID;
                [missingItemIdSet removeObject:itemId];
                PPItem *item = [inventory getItemForId:itemId];
                if (item) {
                    [invItem updateFromItem:item];
                } else {
                    [expiredInvItems addObject:invItem];
                }
            }

            for (PPInventoryItem* invItem in expiredInvItems) {
                [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:invItem];
            }

            for (PPItem *item in [inventory getItemsForIds:[missingItemIdSet allObjects]]) {
                [[item coreDataClass] inventoryItemFromItem:item forUser:self];
            }
        }
        //        if ([self hasChanges]) {
        //            PPLog(@"User %@ has changed keys: %@", self, [[self changedValues] allKeys]);
        //        }
    }
    [super willSave];
}
```